# How this Java Code works ?

Tags: java

I have this code.

```
 class NumberMachine { 
   public static void main(String [] args) { 
     Integer wi1 = new Integer("420"); 
     int i = 101; 
     Integer wi2 = i*420/101; 

     if(wi1 == wi2)
       System.out.print(" =="); 
     if(wi1.equals(wi2))
       System.out.print(" equal"); 
     float f = 1.23f; 
     new NumberMachine().printIt(f); 
  } 

  void printIt(Float f) { 
    System.out.println(" Float"); 
  } 

  void printIt(double d) { 
    System.out.println(" double"); 
  } 
}
```

Why result is "equal double" but no "equal Float" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To determine which method should be called, the compiler goes through the following list, as detailed in the [JLS #5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) and [JLS #15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

- an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
- a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) **==> `printIt(double)` works here**
- a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
- a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference conversion  **==> `printIt(Float)` would be called here if there was no `printIt(double)`**
- an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

Comment: The reasoning behind this being that `widening` has been around longer than `boxing`, so if they didn't do it in this order the behaviour of old code could change.

Comment: @Keppil Absolutely - they actually mention it in JLS#15.12.2.1: *`This guarantees that any calls that were valid in the Java programming language before Java SE 5.0 are not considered ambiguous as the result of the introduction of variable arity methods, implicit boxing and/or unboxing.`*

Answer (score 2):

Because `widening` (float to double) beats [boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

Comment: "while method resolution..." Did you miss some words? Could you please rephrase that part of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

printIt(Float f) accepts the Float object but printIt(double d) accepts the primitive type double.

Thus the second printIt function is called with the float cast to double.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html

You would let the first function be called like this:

```
Float f = new Float(5.0);
printIt(f);
```

Comment: *"printIt(Float f) accepts the Float object, not the primitive type float."* => That's not completely accurate - if there was no `printIt(double)` method, the program would print `equals Float`.